# How to produce a blurred abstract (frosted glass) background like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, background, blur

I have been seeing these blurred backgrounds all over the place, so I would like to know the **exact steps how to reproduce something like [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/918102-Some-icons?list=popular&offset=341)** . What I can imagine, is that they first blurred an image/gradient with a gaussian blur. But there has to be something more to it, right ?

[image]

**+) How do I correctly use a gradient instead of a picture?**

Comment: There really isn't. It's either an image or gradient, or multiple semi-transparent gradients, blurred out and a elyptical vignette to finish it off. Everything else is just tweaking those settings.

Comment: Like the others show, it's really just strongly blurred image. Create a gradient, then use a (gaussian, most likely) blur. That's it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I created a similar effect with the Gaussian Blur tool in Photoshop set to a 60 px radius.

[image]
[image]

Of course, you can do this with any photo where you like the color shifts, your sample reminded me of a beach, so I found a beach photo on Wikimedia.

Another way you can do it is by creating the shapes you want and then applying a Gaussian blur to them:

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 for a good example of using one filter with either a photo/picture or color blocking.

Answer (score 3):

One method: you can shoot a photo with your mobile camera behind frosted glass.

Another: make your DSLR camera lens out of focus sufficiently in your viewfinder and shoot.